# BlackBerry emulator not connecting to internet

Tags: blackberry, proxy, emulation

My BB emulator cannot connect to the internet. I'm behind a proxy and have entered the following in my rimpublic.property under the [HTTP HANDLER] heading.

```
application.handler.http.proxyEnabled = true
application.handler.http.proxyHost=PROXY_NAME
application.handler.http.proxyPort=PROXY_PORT
application.handler.http.proxyUser=PROXY_USER
application.handler.http.proxyPass=PROXY_PASSWORD
```

I have BB JDE 5.0.0 installed. I am able to successfully start the MDS service and do get the screen to stay open but do not see any errors. I've read every question on SO regarding similar issues but nothing works. Also, I am starting the MDS service before booting my emulator. If it helps, I'm using the emulator 5.0.0.545 (9700).

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running the MDS through run configurations or the Stand-alone MDS?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the stand-alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its the standalone MDS server you may be running into an issue with them not talking to each other. I found it far easier to just adjust the configuration of the MDS server that can launch with the phone, and selecting the run option through launch configurations.

You can find the MDS server at the following location:

```
{Eclipse Dir.}\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack[version-number]\components\MDS\config
```

Alter the rimpublic.property file that you changed before with the correct values.

Then in Eclipse go to your run configurations.

```
Right Click > Run As > Run Configurations
```

Click the 'Simulator' tab for your Blackberry Simulator run configuration, and check the "Launch Mobile Data System Connection Service (MDS-CS) with simulator" box.

When you run, all should be well.

---

Also important to note, that this is only for the browser interacting with sites. If your trying to access a site using an app, I believe you need to pass the appropriate proxy headers yourself, through the app. There is a url property that is supposed to use the MDS when searching urls, but it didn't work for me when I tried it.

Comment: Thank you. This was the working solution for me. And you were right about the MDS not being able to talk to the emulator. :)

Comment: I have MDS v4.1.4 installed plus BlackBerry Simulator v6.0.0.141. I have my config file setup with the HTTP proxy settings. But after starting MDS (command window then stays resident with lots of jargon), then starting my simulator, the simulator's browser nav is still going around my proxy. Fiddler doesn't register any activity when navigating the web. Wassap???

Answer (score 1):

What exactly did you do to check the internet connection on the emulator ? 
Open the browser in the emulator and try to open any website ? Or something else ?

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Opened the browser and went to Google. Is there perhaps a way to test the BB browser outside of the emulator excluding the physical device?

Comment: Maybe M$ Windows firewall blocked your simulator network traffic.

Comment: The Microsoft firewall is disabled.

Comment: Did you append ";deviceside=true" to the http URL?

Comment: Yesterday I tried without even editing/inserting the rimpublic property file, and it can connect to the internet (using 8330 simulator). and I was even started the MDS after the simulator running.
Are you sure you use proxy ?
Can you ping your proxy from your simulator ? (Home menu -> Manage Connection -> menu Mobile Network Options -> menu tools -> ping.
Do you use proxy server name or IP address ? Try to use this alternately.