# Unexpected response code:403 when calling image in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Right now i am working on Image download from web.For this i set http connection like below code.

```
HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
```

I am calling two images from web.for one picture it display image successfully.But for other picture it show error Unexpected response code:403.I am not understand why this problem is occur.How can i download image from web.Is there any change in HttpConnection need to modify.

Please help me.

Comment: HTTP 403 means "Forbidden."  Are you sure that you have the appropriate permissions to access the second file?

Comment: it accessing when i am calling from browser.In android and iphone its working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this on a real phone, or just in the emulator?

If you are using the emulator, make sure you've configured it to connect to the internet, it won't be configured to do that by default.
[BlackBerry emulator not connecting to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006280/blackberry-emulator-not-connecting-to-internet)

Answer (score -1):

Use this function , as we get bytes from the http connection,you need to convert those bytes into image this function will do that for you , just pass the url of the image in arguments:

```
public static Bitmap connectServerForImage(String url) {
    HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
    DataOutputStream httpDataOutput = null;
    InputStream httpInput = null;
    int rc;
    Bitmap bitmp = null;
    try {
        httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
        rc = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
        }
        httpInput = httpConnection.openInputStream();
        InputStream inp = httpInput;
        byte[] b = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inp);
        EncodedImage hai = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, b.length);
        int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(hai.getWidth());
        int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(hai.getHeight());
        int reqWidth = 48;
        int reqHeight = 35;
        int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(reqWidth);
        int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(reqHeight);
        int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32, requiredWidthFixed32);
        int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32, requiredHeightFixed32);
        hai = hai.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);
        return hai.getBitmap();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("URL Bitmap Error........" +url+ ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (httpInput != null)
                    httpInput.close();
                if (httpDataOutput != null)
                    httpDataOutput.close();
                if (httpConnection != null)
                    httpConnection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return bitmp;
        }
```