# Not able to connect to internet from blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am working on a blackberry application, when i connect to jpulse(vpn), we are not able to connect to internet in blackberry simulator.But without vpn connection,internet works fine in simulator. I tried by running MDS, but didnt get any results. Please provide me solution. I am using simulator 9900.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably when you are connected to VPN then your routing table has been changed and your computer tries to access the Internet via this VPN.

To overcome this open your TCPIP network settings and setup manually the gateway which should be used to access the Internet.

Comment: +1.  Many VPN clients will also have a **split tunnel** feature that can be enabled, which allows normal applications to function, while keeping the VPN open at the same time.

Comment: @Rafael Thanks for your reply. I am able to connect to internet from my device, But not from blackberrry simulator. I must be connected to internet from BB Simulator when connected to vpn.

Comment: @user2652629 configure your MDS simulator properties to use non-VPN gateway to access the Internet. Properties are located in `rimpublic.property` file in MDS simulator configuration folder. Here is the sample location path: `Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulators 4.1.2\MDS\config\ `. For your case it can be a bit different, but I think you get the point.

Comment: @user2652629 and check this link: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Configure-the-BlackBerry-MDS-Simulator-to-work-behind-a-proxy/ta-p/446115

Comment: I have the same path C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulators 4.1.4\MDS\config,

Comment: I have the same path C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulators 4.1.4\MDS\config,but in rimpublic.property file am not able to find the HTTP Handler sections as its mentioned in the above link... so how will i update those fields

Comment: I do not have MDS simulator installed on my computer and I cannot check it now, sorry. Does this property file contain http proxy settings? Maybe under other sections. And check this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006280/blackberry-emulator-not-connecting-to-internet